# Communicating "Internet Java EE" application with "Intranet Spring" application

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, web, architecture

We have two already running applications one is **internet** ***Java EE*** application and another one is **intranet** ***spring*** based application deployed in two different servers which need to communicate with each other for some functionalities.

1) What is the best way to communicate between these two applications?

2) In future after merging both functionalities, if we want to sunset one among these applications and make other use for both *Intranet and Internet* users what is the best suggesion to follow?

Comment: I'd suggest using webservices (REST is quite popular these days) for the communication. As for the merge, that highly depends on your architecture and plans for the future and IMHO is too specialized a question for SO.

Comment: What is best would depend on the kind of communication.

Answer (score 0):

> Option 1: Best option in my opinion:

Both the internet and intranet applications are running in your network. So take the libraries out of the spring intranet application and embed into the other Java EE application. There will be wiring required. If the internet application also uses spring for wiring then it should be smooth. Now all you have is one application running on same jvm. This might need time for integration and consolidation of data transfer objects.

> Option2:

Within the intranet spring application create a wrapper service that exposes the service as a REST API. This should be quick to achieve and can serve as a short term solution. Later, use option 1 to merge them into a single application when you are ready. Another approach is to append modules in the intranet application into the internet application and expose the functionality.